# How can I improve my precision when performing a split kick?

Tags: tae-kwon-do, kicking

For my next grading, I'm planning to demonstrate a split-kick break, similar to the kick shown here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ox46E-GNVQ8&feature=related
(In case the video becomes unavailable, the technique involves a flying kick, jumping between two boards held facing each other, chambering both legs and turning the hips, performing a front- or round-house to the board on one side, and a side-kick to the board on the other, both kicks hitting simultaneously.)

I can perform the kick reasonably well, but I'm having trouble with targeting: if I look forwards, I have no trouble breaking the front board (the side the video refers to as a roundhouse), but I hit the other board off-centre and don't break with the sidekick. Same goes, in reverse, if I focus on the sidekick.

Are there any drills I can use to improve my aim on the board I'm not focusing on? Or is my focus in the wrong place? How can I ensure I break both boards every time?

Comment: Its about timing and practice, keep practicing. Sometimes kick earlier, some times later. Whatever timing works use. By the way, the choreography in that movie isn't up to par with the rest of Hong Kongs movies. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precision comes with practice.  There is no other way.  However, there are a few things that you can do to help that practice be more purposeful.

- **Video**.  It's amazing how many mistakes are made manifest by an unforgiving lens.  It will help you judge things like your approach, accuracy, body position, etc.
- **Field of Vision**.  You mentioned that you can accurately kick what you are looking at.  In the video you displayed, the attacker was looking straight ahead.  My guess is that he had an eye on the targets using his peripheral vision.
- **Reusable Targets**.  It might be useful to use a target printed on paper to help you focus.  Once a board breaks it's done.  If you have the paper on something stiff but has give, you can reuse the targets to keep working on your accuracy.  For example, tacking the targets on a pair of heavy bags might work well for you.

The goal here is to apply fairly equal power in the right location.  Focusing on one target or another can affect your body position--particularly in air.  Focusing on the sidekick might have you over-rotate, and focusing on the front kick might have you under-rotate.

Comment: Video. Good idea. +1

Comment: I'm definitely going to give the video a shot. I'll keep the question open for now in case others have good input.
I have been kicking foam targets as well - way too expensive to kick timber all day long!

Comment: Ya never know.  My instructor was amazing at pointing out these little things that made it so much better.  He would adjust my posture or some little footwork bug, and that would be enough.